# how to uninstall the jdk 1.7.0 in the ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

i encounter a very strange problem,and here is the detail:
i'm going to uninstall the jdk 1.7.0.but when i use the rpm to check the appropriate name of the package,it prompt nothing.Anyway,when i use the command `java -version`,it will prompt the detail of the jdk 1.7.0.
below is the detail:

```
root@kaiwiiho:/usr/java# rpm -qa|grep jdk
root@kaiwiiho:/usr/java# java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
root@kaiwiiho:/usr/java# rpm -qa|grep jdk
root@kaiwiiho:/usr/java#
```

so what happen?And how can i uninstall it?thx

Comment: This is off-topic.  I recommend the "superusers" sister site for this kind of question.

Comment: ubuntu doesn't use rpm?

Comment: voted for superuser...write in for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: rpm packages are for Red Hat / Fedora-based Linux distributions. Debian-based Linux distributions such as Ubuntu use a different package format (deb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu?  The process would be

```
$ dpkg -l | grep jdk
```

Then remove with

```
$ apt-get purge <packagename>
```

If you're brave, you could

```
$ apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep jdk | awk '{print $2}')
```

(It should still prompt you, though.)

Comment: root@kaiwiiho:/usr/java# dpkg -l | grep jdk
ii  gcj-4.5-jdk                           4.5.2-8ubuntu1                               gcj and classpath development tools for Java(TM)
ii  gcj-jdk                               4:4.5.2-1ubuntu3                             gcj and classpath development tools for Java(TM)
ii  sun-java6-jdk                         6.26-2lucid1                                 Sun Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 6
it seems nothing about jdk 1.7.did i do something wrong,when i installed the jdk 1.7?

Comment: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM sounds like the Sun Java implementation.  Those packages are named sun-java*.  grep for "sun-java" instead:
dpkg -l | grep sun-java

Comment: You can also find out what's what using update-alternatives --display java.  That should give a hint as to which package is providing "java".

Comment: well,i try it.but i feel confused there is nothing about 1.7.0 about 1.6

Comment: don't forget on ubuntu, you don't login as root, so you'll have to prepend "sudo" to the commands you are executing which actualy remove the package (ie. the apt-get)